# Getting Can't locate object method "new" via package "PDF::FromHTML"

Tags: perl

Can't locate object method 
1. "new" via package "PDF::FromHTML" (perhaps you forgot
to load "PDF::FromHTML"?) at C:\Govind\Performance Logs\Performance Report HTML
\html2pdf.pl line 1.

Please help!!!

Comment: As it stands, this does not contain a question. I recommend you read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, the error message includes an obvious hint to what you probably did wrong…

Comment: when i am loading the PDF::FromHTML using command "use PDF::FromHTML" it is throwing error:
Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/
Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/
lib/PDF/FromHTML/Twig.pm line 5.

Comment: And why do you think that is? Perhaps because you don't have XML::Twig installed and PDF::FromHTML depends on it?

Answer (score 1):

Use CPAN to install XML::Twig

From SSH:

```
cpan
install XML::Twig
```

Answer (score 0):

That module is not installed. So you need to install it from CPAN.
Linux command 
sudo cpan 
then install ModuleName 
Here your module name is PDF::FromHTML

Similarly you can use following link to understand better.

https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::FromHTML